# No puedo acceder al código de mi proyecto

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo un proyecto de una página web creada con Laravel que aloje en 000webhost.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La historia es que quiero acceder a esa página para modificar el código, pero cada vez que quiero acceder a la página, me sale este mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ignoro la advertencia y entro, llego a una página en blanco.
A la página web y a la BBDD sigo pudiendo acceder.
Parece ser que el problema esta en mi conexión a Internet, porque cuando lo hago fuera de casa, si que puedo acceder.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen es de cuando active los datos para acceder desde un teléfono Android. Si lo hago desde ese mismo telefono, pero usando la red Wi-Fi de mi casa, me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo arreglar mi conexión para que no me de estos fallos?

Answer (score 0):

es la politica de seguridad de firefox porque no reconoce el https como seguro, 
prueba lo siguiente :

1) cuando te salga el mensaje de error le das click en "avanzado"

2) añadir excepción

3) confirmar la excepcón de seguridad

aca te dejo una imagen para solucionarlo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He probado eso, pero al conseguir entrar llego a una página en blanco. De hecho, tengo el mismo problema en otros exploradores, como Chrome, Opera y Internet Explorer.